# myDate cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, variables, calendar

I'm getting an error on the line:

```
cal.setTime(myDate);
```

stating "myDate cannot be resolved to a variable" however when I attempt to move the line it references:

```
Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
```

above it - I get a new error stating: "prefs cannot be resolved"

...any suggestions?

SOURCE:

```
    public class WifiMonitor extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);

        // get traffic info
        double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
        totalBytes /= 1000000;
        mobileBytes /= 1000000;
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
        String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
        String info = String.format(
                "Wifi Data Usage: %s MB\tMobile Data Usage: %s MB", totalStr,
                mobileStr);
        infoView.setText(info);

        // send traffic info via sms
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, info, null, null);
        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

        // get the current date
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // convert the date to milliseconds
        long millis = date.getTime();

        // save the date to shared preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        // SharedPreferences prefs = millis;
        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
        // .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        editor.putLong("time", date.getTime());
        editor.commit();

        // get the saved date

        Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
    }

    // set the alarm to expire 30 days from the date stored in sharePreferences
    public void invokeAlarm(long invokeTime, long rowId) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Alarm.class);
        i.putExtra("rowId", String.valueOf(rowId));
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, PendingIntent.getService(
                this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, 0));

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(myDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        invokeAlarm(cal.getTimeInMillis(), rowId);
    }

}
```

Comment: you'll get better reponses if you tag the language you're using

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `Date myDate` as a member of the class.

```
     private Date myDate;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            /**/
            myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
         }

public void invokeAlarm(long invokeTime, long rowId) {
        /**/
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(myDate != null)
           cal.setTime(myDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        invokeAlarm(cal.getTimeInMillis(), rowId);
    }
```

Or if you're getting your date directly from the sharedPrefs :

```
public void invokeAlarm(long invokeTime, long rowId) {
        /**/

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        invokeAlarm(cal.getTimeInMillis(), rowId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have myDate declared in one function (local scope to function) and are trying to use it in another function (different scope).

To be able to do that, without major changes, declare myDate at a class level, assign it in one function, use it in the other. Be sure to change the line:

```
Date myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
```

to:

```
myDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", 0));
```

when you do so.